# Monitor the content of a cached object during debug

Tags: c#, caching, monitoring

I have a cached generic list which behaves very strange in a generic handler (.ashx).

```
List<Sale> l1 = new List<Sale>();
l1 = (List<Sale>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("list");

doSomething();

List<Sale> l2 = new List<Sale>();
l2 = (List<Sale>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("list");

doSomething();

List<Sale> l3 = new List<Sale>();
l3 = (List<Sale>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("list");

doSomething();
```

As I step through the code, the lists `l1`, `l2` and `l3` keeps changing their content for unknown reasons. Is there any way to monitor the cached list during debug to see exactly when it changes?

Comment: You are saying that they change and that doSomething() has nothing to do with that? Also, do you realize that l1, l2 and l3 all point to the same list?

Comment: Yes, that was the point. My primitive way of tracking the content of that cached object. The content of `list` keeps changing as I step through the code. I do modify the cache in a couple of places, in `doSomething()`, but not necessarily the cached object `list`, so I want to know where and why it changes.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it changes?

Comment: The list changes in length. After the first `doSomething()`, it contains 768 `Sale`, and as I step through the code it keeps increasing to 1299 `Sale` after the last `doSomething()`. Even stranger is that previous lists updates along the way, so `l2` might start out as 768 but increases to 1299 once the code runs the last `doSomething()`

Comment: Obviously the content of `list` changes in those `doSomething()`, for reasons I don't understand, but what I need is another way to monitor it's content so that I can step into `doSomething` and follow the content of `list` and see where it changes.

Comment: show us all the code that touches the cache, if possible.

Comment: When you say *"Even stranger is that previous lists updates along the way"*, that is normal because l1, l2 and l3 are all pointing to the same list. So when one of these changes, the others change too.